# Transitioning image with overflow

Tags: css, overflow, transition, onhover

I'm trying to use transition on an image. Here is what i'd like it to do. On hover, the image should increase in size to a width of 400 x 400px.

What I don't want it to do when it does transition is:

(1) affect any other element on the page.

(2) hide the image when it exceeds it's original size (where i'm having the overflow:hidden; issue.)

Here is my code taken into another document so I can work on it without looking at all the rest of the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
#test img {width:358px;
           height:298px;
           transition: all 1s ease;
           overflow: hidden;}

#test:hover img {width: 450px;
                 height:400px;}
</style>

<div id="test"> 
<img src="Portfolio/Hair_Salon/images/stylist1.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured it out...

Comment: I needed to add one more identifier #test {width:358px, height:298px; overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out as soon as i thought about what i was typing on here...

I needed to add one more identifier #test {width:358px, height:298px; overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

You should put `overflow:hidden`, `height`, and `width` on `#test`. Then set your img width 100% to `#test`

Here's working example

```
#test {
  width : 358px;
  height : 298px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#test img {
   width : 100%;
   height : 100%;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}
#test img:hover {
  width: 450px;
  height:400px;
}

<div id="test">
  <img src="http://www.nzhistory.net.nz/files/hero_jean-batten-1934_1.jpg">
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mc6v6r71/